# Upload Failed n google play store

Tags: android

I have an app in the Play Store. I have updated the app three times earlier but never got the error while updating the apk. Now when I am trying to update the apk with the same fingerprint ".jks" file I am getting the below mentioned error.

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
>
> ```
> [SHA1: D1:------------------------------:7E ]
> ```
>
> and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
>
> ```
> [ SHA1: A2:------------------------------:31 ].
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is occurring because your update APK is signed with a different keystore than your old version (and for this reason has a different SHA1 fingerprint).

Resign your app with the right keystore and then reupload it to the Play Store.

See more information regarding signing your Android app before publishing [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).

Comment: I tried with the same keystore and I have checked the sha key, both are same. Then also it gives the same error.

Comment: Can you please try checking your SHA1 fingerprint of your keystore from Terminal/CMD and comparing it with what the Google Play Developer Console is saying?